# how to resolve this casting problem in java RMI?

Tags: java, rmi

***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to RMI.bonjourInterface1
at RMI.Client.main(Client.java:12)***

BonjourClass

```
package RMI;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class BonjourClass extends UnicastRemoteObject{
    public BonjourClass() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }
    public String Bonjour(String name) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Bonjour si sayed "+name ;
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
package RMI;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
public interface bonjourInterface1 extends Remote {
    String Bonjour(String name) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Server.java:

```
package RMI;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            BonjourClass salutation = new BonjourClass();
            Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/Bonjour", (Remote) salutation);
            System.out.println(" Server jawou behy  ");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Client.java:

```
package RMI;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        bonjourInterface1 stub = (bonjourInterface1) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/Bonjour");
            System.out.println(" Put you name please ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            String res = stub.Bonjour(name);
            System.out.println(res);
        }
    }
```

the problem is in the casting inst line i can't find why even i installed the JDK correctly

Comment: You need `public class BonjourClass extends UnicastRemoteObject extends bonjourInterface1`.